# App context root path prepended to external link

Tags: java, spring, jsp, href

Organizations registering on my application can provide their external websites url for their profile page. The resulting html when displaying the link to their site is `<a href=​"example.com" rel=​"nofollow">​example.com​</a>​` (Confirmed by inspecting the page in chrome). When hovering over the link or actually clicking it. The url is apparently interpreted as relative and `https://localhost:8443/MyWebApp/profile/` is prepended to it.

Do I have to check and possibly modify links that users input or is there likely something in my configuration that is causing this behavior?

EDIT: Is there a simple method of countering this? Such as a jsp tag or using a url rewriter? (Tuckey)

Comment: You have to provide the protocol to make it an absolute URL.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour. Since the provided URL does not begin with a protocol (http, https, ftp, whatever) it is considered relative, and since it does not start with a /, it is considered relative to the current URL.